# Applescript: Why are "headers" in a message sometimes not the complete list?

Tags: applescript, mail.app

This script (below) is triggered by a Mail Rule for every message.  **Sometimes** when the script runs due to a new incoming message, the list of headers is not complete and my debug lists only `from`, `date`, `to`, `message-id`, `content-type`, and `subject`.  The message ends up in my *Inbox*.  I have seen it get all of the headers when triggered via an incoming message.

I can select the message and run **Apply Rules** and then it will see all of the headers (19 in this last case) and the script will work as expected.

It seems that sometimes, for some reason, the `headers` element of a message is not complete.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to always get the full list of headers?

```
    using terms from application "Mail"
      on perform mail action with messages these_messages for rule this_rule
        set debug_level to 4
        set junk_limit to 50
        set extreme_limit to 100
        if debug_level > 0 then my logit("Start Perform")
        tell application "Mail"
          set the message_count to the count of these_messages
          repeat with i from 1 to the message_count
            try
              set this_score to -9999
              set this_message to item i of these_messages
              try
                set this_subject to (subject of this_message) as Unicode text
              on error
                set this_subject to "**Error on Subject"
              end try
              if debug_level > 1 then my logit("  " & this_subject)
              set these_headers to headers of this_message
              set header_count to the count of these_headers
              if debug_level > 3 then my logit("    Header Count: " & header_count)
              repeat with j from 1 to the header_count
                set this_header to item j of these_headers
                set this_name to name of this_header
                set this_content to content of this_header
                if debug_level > 3 then my logit("    Header: " & this_name)
                if this_name = "x-spam-score" then
                  try
                    set this_score to this_content as number
                  on error errStr number errNum
                    set this_score to -2
                  end try
                  if debug_level > 2 then my logit("    Score: " & this_score)
                  exit repeat
                end if
              end repeat
              if debug_level > 2 and this_score = -9999 then my logit("    Score not set")
              if this_score > extreme_limit then
                set theAccount to account of mailbox of this_message
                move this_message to mailbox "Extreme Junk" of theAccount
                if debug_level > 1 then my logit("  Moved to Extreme Junk")
              else if this_score > junk_limit then
                set theAccount to account of mailbox of this_message
                move this_message to mailbox "Junk" of theAccount
                if debug_level > 1 then my logit("  Moved to Junk")
              else
                if debug_level > 1 then my logit("  Not Moved")
              end if
            on error errStr number errNum
              my logit("*** Err: " & errStr & " " & errNum)
            end try
          end repeat
        end tell
        if debug_level > 0 then my logit("End Perform")
      end perform mail action with messages
    end using terms from

    to logit(log_string)
      do shell script ¬
        "echo `date '+%Y-%m%d %T: '`\"" & log_string & "\" >> $HOME/Library/Logs/ExtremeJunk.log"
    end logit
```

Comment: What headers, specifically, are you looking for?  Are you sure that specific message has those headers to begin with?  Not all emails contain all headers.  Per [RFC 822](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc822/), only "Date", "From", "To" are required for all email messages.

Comment: @vykor I'm looking for the X-Spam-Score header.  Yes, I know that all headers are not always present but I know there are times where many more headers are present that are not showing up.  I can find the mail message via the Subject line because that's part of my debug and then display the raw message.  Its weird, I realize.  Especially since sometimes it can find all the headers and sometimes it finds only a small subset.